# No "Trusted Execution" on Xeon E5540, what am I missing?

Tags: intel, xeon, nx

I seems the [Xeon E5540](http://ark.intel.com/products/37104/) ticks all the "fun" boxes for Hyper-V (especially VT-d) on Windows Server 2012. The only one conspicuously missing is "Trusted Execution".

I read the information on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Execution_Technology) and [Intel's page](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/trusted-execution-technology/malware-reduction-general-technology.html). If I understand it correctly it enables the OS to mark data as non-executable and prevent attacks in various ways.

So I understand it's generally a good thing to have. Question then becomes: If I use this CPU (or another CPU w/o Trusted Execution) in my Hyper-V servers, how am I potentially shooting myself in the foot? What features will I NOT be able to use?

Comment: FYI- Trusted execution does not "enables the OS to mark data as non-executable". That is Data Execution Prevention and the NX bit. Trusted Execution uses code signing to verify that only authorized code is allowed to be loaded and executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chips with the "Trusted Execution" basically allow EFI booting to work correctly and to make use of a TPM module. Since you're using Hyper-V, there's no purpose for this technology. Most Xeons that I've seen actually lack this feature in particular anyway.

Comment: Thanks, EFI Booting indeed isn't a priority. At least not at the moment (unless I'll need to start booting from GPD partitioned drives..).